# Animating a view & its subview separately

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewanimation, uianimation

I have a view `interface` which contains a subview `touchWheel`. On clicking a minimise button on `interface` I'd like to perform a transform & send the view to the bottom-right corner of my screen. The thing is that I want to "detach" the `touchWheel` view & send it to the corner separately with the parent-view, `interface`, following behind (& in fact fading out).

when I try this I encounter a problem. My animation works fine initially & `touchWheel` is sent towards the bottom corner, as desired. When `touchWheel` is about half-way to its destination I animate `interface` so that it follows `touchWheel`.

Once `interface` starts animating it appears to control `touchWheel` & `touchWheel` changes course.

It seems that `interface` still retains control of `touchWheel` since it's its parent view.

```
- (void)hideInterfaceButtonClicked : (id) sender
{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"RemoveGrey" object:self];

   //Remove Views & transform
   [touchWheel removeViews];
   interfaceHidden = YES;

      //Send Interface to corner

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.25
                  delay:0.0
                options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn
             animations:^{
                 // Move to the right

                 CGAffineTransform translateInterface = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(437,200); 
                 // Scale
                 CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.135,0.135);   

                 // Apply them to the view
                 self.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(scale, translateInterface);

                self.alpha = 0.0;

             } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                 NSLog(@"Animation Has Stopped");
                 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"hiddenInterfaceViewNeeded" object:self]; //after MoveView finishes


             }]; 



}
```

Making `touchWheel` subview of something other than `interface` creates other problems which would complicate things further.

Any ideas how one might get around this issue? any tips greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

1. Move `touchWheel` to the `interface`'s superview, recalculating its frame using `convertRect:toView:` so that `touchWheel` appears to have the same window coordinates.
2. Animate both the views to their final locations.
3. In the completion block of the animation do the opposite of step 1: make `touchWheel` a subview of `interface`, recalculating its frame again.

It doesn't seem too complicated, but there's a caveat: you may want to temporarily disable the maximize button (or whatever the appropriate control is) to prevent the maximize action during the animation. Otherwise, this approach will cause unpredictable results.

Comment: This is the solution I came up with in the end, as well :)

Comment: @costique, Could you please answer similar question posted here.. https://stackoverflow.com/q/46053072/2534233