# Unable to minimize subview alongside mainView during animation

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation, uianimation

I have two views, videoView (which is the mainView) and subVideoView (which is the subView of mainView).

I am trying to minimize both views using animation at the same time, as shown in the below code. I am able to minimize the videoView (i.e mainView) and not the subVideoView.

However, when I hide code for minimising videoView (i.e mainView), I am able to minimise the subVideoView.

I believe it has to do something with the way I am animating.

Can some one please advice how I can minimise both views (proportionally) with animation at the same time and end up with the below result.

[image]

**RESULTS OF EXISTING CODE**
[image]

```
func minimiseOrMaximiseViews(animationType: String){


        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: [],

            animations: { [unowned self] in  
                switch animationType {
                case "minimiseView" :

                    // Minimising subVideoView

                    self.subVideoView.frame =   CGRect(x:       self.mainScreenWidth - self.minSubVideoViewWidth - self.padding,
                                                       y:       self.mainScreenHeight - self.minSubVideoViewHeight - self.padding,
                                                       width:   self.minSubVideoViewWidth,
                                                       height:  self.minSubVideoViewHeight)

                    // Minimising self i.e videoView

                    self.frame = CGRect(x:      self.mainScreenWidth - self.videoViewWidth - self.padding,
                                        y:      self.mainScreenHeight - self.videoViewHeight - self.padding,
                                        width:  self.videoViewWidth,
                                        height: self.videoViewHeight)

                    self.layoutIfNeeded()

                case "maximiseView":

                    // Maximising videoView

                    self.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.mainScreenSize.width, height: self.mainScreenSize.height)

                    // Maximising subVideoView

                    self.subVideoView.frame =   CGRect(x:       self.mainScreenWidth - self.maxSubVideoViewWidth - self.padding,
                                                       y:       self.mainScreenHeight - self.maxSubVideoViewHeight - self.padding - self.buttonStackViewBottomPadding - buttonStackViewHeight,
                                                       width:   self.maxSubVideoViewWidth,
                                                       height:  self.maxSubVideoViewHeight) 
                default:
                    break
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement add **subViews** in **mainView** and set

```
mainView.clipsToBounds = true
```

and In the `minimiseOrMaximiseViews` method you just need to manage **Y** axis of **mainView** for show and hide.

Comment: I would like to minimise the view, that is reduce the view size. I do not want to clipsToBounds as it just clips and does not reduce the view size.

Comment: @moritz, added detailed images to better explain the issue

Answer (score 0):

I could minimise both views simultaneously using animation, when I've set both views (videoView and subVideoView) as subViews of window i.e `UIApplication.shared.keywindow`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, this kind of animation is much more easily achieved by animating the `transform` property of the `videoView` (the main view). You will need to concatenate scaling and translation transforms for that, because scaling is by default applied to a view's center.

The trick is that applying a transform to a view affects all its subviews automatically, e.g. applying a scaling transform to a view scales both the view and all its subviews.

To make a reverse animation just set `videoView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity` inside an animation block.

**Caveat**: You should be careful, though, with the `frame` property of a transformed view. The `frame` property is synthetic and is derived from `bounds`, `center` and `transform`. This means that setting a view's `frame` resets its `transform` property. In other words, if you manipulate your views using `transform`, you most likely want to avoid setting their frames directly.